# Open camera in facebook messenger webview

Tags: iframe, webview, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm developing a bot and I need to open a camera in WebView. It turns out, I can't open the camera with the following error (in desktop Chrome):

> VideoCapture permission has been blocked because of a Feature Policy
>   applied to the current document.

I'm using the following code to request for permissions:

```
        const constraints = {
            advanced: [{
                facingMode: "environment"
            }]
        };
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({
                video: constraints
            }).catch(error => {
                view.handlePermissionError(error);
            })
            .then(stream => {
                console.log('Permission success');

                this.videoBlock.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                this.videoBlock.width = document.body.clientWidth;
                this.videoBlock.height = document.body.clientHeight;
                this.canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
                this.canvas.height = this.videoBlock.videoHeight;
                this.setOkDimensions();
                this.videoBlock.play();
            });
```

Apparently, a similar error is blocking it in Messenger on mobile.

Is there a way to safely request for permission inside a messenger bot iframe?

EDIT: Iframe is opened with HTTPS

Comment: Did you find a way to allow media inside messenger web view ?

Comment: @SandunTharaka unfortunately no. My workaround was to check user agent and if it is inside facebook messenger webview, to show the user a screenshot showing how to open "in browser". It works fine in browser, so...  You can use the following code to determine if it's inside the webview:

`
         function isFacebookApp() {
            let ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
            return (ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1);
        }`